# Ubuntu 16.04 VPS dropping massive amount of RX Packets

Tags: ubuntu, networking, ubuntu-16.04, ifconfig, slow-connection

Having networking issues with a Ubuntu 16.04 VPS, causing extremely slow speeds (we're talking about 100kbps). Running ifconfig is showing over a million dropped RX packets from eth0 (no errors) and I can't seem to track it down.

Here's my ifconfig result:

```
eth0      
      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:16:3e:48:31:13  
      inet addr:193.183.98.250  Bcast:193.183.99.255  Mask:255.255.254.0
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:61116519 errors:0 dropped:1068053 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:200565774 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:1003044768 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:3388296345 (3.3 GB)  TX bytes:23453596552 (23.4 GB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1136031 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1136031 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:124953065 (124.9 MB)  TX bytes:124953065 (124.9 MB)
```

Also checking things out with ethtool -g eht0 is showing (what seems to be) lower than typical settings:

```
Ring parameters for eth0:
Pre-set maximums:
RX:         64
RX Mini:    0
RX Jumbo:   0
TX:         64

Current hardware settings:
RX:         64
RX Mini:    0
RX Jumbo:   0
TX:         64
```

Tried to increase RX ring buffer (ethtool -G eth0 rx 256), but I get "Cannot set device ring parameters: Operation not supported"

From looking at other questions, I've seen a few things they've included to try and help:

## ip -4 route show

```
default via 193.183.98.1 dev eth0 onlink 
193.183.98.0/23 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 193.183.98.250
```

Any suggestions on how to track this down? Am I on the wrong path completely? The host is no help at all either, unfortunately.

Comment: First contact your VPS provider.

Comment: I have, but they've been very unhelpful! Their only suggestion was we might be experiencing a DDOS, but I find that very unlikely to be the case since this has been an issue since the VPS was provisioned. 

Do you think that with the above it could be purely an issue on their/the hardware end that I should push?

Comment: It's almost certainly an issue with their host. It is, after all, a virtual network interface. If they refuse to fix it, go find another VPS. There's no shortage of providers.

Comment: Ok, thank you! That has been my gut feeling, but I'm really not a networking guy.

Comment: I did take a moment to do a Google search for dropped network packets on Xen guests, and everything I could come up with is instructions for the hosting provider to track down the problem. Nothing about it being a problem in the guest.